# Designing composite webservices

Tags: java, web-services, composite

How you do design composite webservices. Are there any frameworks available to let the developer simply concentrate on bussiness logic and to implement composite frameworks with some simple configuration.

I have read about SCA. But seems there is very less implementations of it.

Can some one suggest are there any frameworks which support ease of developing the composite webservices

Answer (score 1):

An ESB caters this aspect to some extent. Please have a look at the open source [WSO2 ESB](http://wso2.org/library/esb) built on top of Apache Synapse.

The WSO2 ESB comes with a large number of samples and please have a look at [this](http://wso2.org/project/esb/java/4.0.0/docs/samples/advanced_mediation_samples.html#Sample400) sample too....

Thanks...